# How to set hardcode credentials aws-sdk php SesClient

Tags: php, aws-sdk, amazon-ses, aws-php-sdk

I'm trying to use SesClient from aws sdk php to send email but it returns the following error

```
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;


$SesClient = new SesClient([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => KEY,,
                'secret' => SECRET
            ],
        ]);
```

But I get the following error

```
Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials
```

And the most curious thing is that with S3Client it works perfectly when I pass the credentials as hard code

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;


$s3Client = new S3Client([
                'version'     => 'latest',
                'region'      => 'us-east-1',
                'credentials' => [
                    'key'    => KEY,
                    'secret' => SECRET,
                ],
            ]);
```

Describe what you tried, what you hoped would happen, and what actually worked. Minimum of 20 characters.

I tried to pass hardcode credentials like in S3Client which worked perfectly but in SesClient it doesn't work

Comment: The code you posted has 2 commas after KEY for SesClient.  Typo or actual error in code?